# Creating a Gem that adds a method to a core class

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a gem that adds a new method to the `String` class. For instance if I were creating a method that added the `to_foobar` on `String` I know that I can simply do:

```
class String
  def to_foobar
    # ...
  end
end
```

But is this the right way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: Looks right to me, Another option is to put the code in a module and then only extend String for specific use cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer

```
# my_gem/lib/my_gem/core_extensions/string.rb

module MyGem::CoreExtensions::String
  def to_foobar
    # ...
  end
end

class String
  include MyGem::CoreExtensions::String
end
```

That way, if I get for example an error message mentioning `String#to_foobar`, I don't have to wonder "Wait, `String` doesn't have a `to_foobar` method, where is that coming from?" I can just say

```
String.ancestors
# => [String, MyGem::CoreExtensions::String, Comparable, Object, Kernel]
```

Et voilà, there's this suspicious looking module in the ancestry chain, which, following standard Ruby naming conventions, probably lives in `my_gem/lib/my_gem/core_extensions/string.rb`.

Or, I can say

```
''.method(:to_foobar).owner
# => MyGem::CoreExtensions::String
```

And actually get a meaningful answer.

Of course,

```
''.method(:to_foobar).source_location
# => ['my_gem-0.0.1/lib/my_gem/core_extensions/string.rb", 4]
```

always works.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I got my answer and learned a couple of useful methods along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. If you don't know how to build a gem from scratch, I recommend that you take a look at [jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler).